# Plane extraction in 3D data

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst, point-clouds

What is the best way to:
1. Detect a plane in a set of 3D points with high noise around part of it (not all the points)?

2. Extract plane equation of two intersection planes in 3D data.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use the [pcfitplane](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcfitplane.html) function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.